# Tcl use different way to format a function call

Tags: formatting, tcl

I use functions and some of them have alot of arguments. This becomes very difficult to work with if i try to adjust an argument:

```
callingfunction "argument1" "argument2 is longer" "argument3 is even more long" "argument4 is short again" "and then there are agrguments that are far longer than anything else seen before"
```

So is there a possibility in TCL to reformat this area so the function call works without any issues but in the editor i could use a formatting that provides a better overview? Something like:

```
callingfunction {
  "argument1",
  "argument2 is longer",
  "argument3 is even more long",
  "argument4 is short again",
  "and then there are agrguments that are far longer than anything else seen before"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't need Tcl to do any substitution on the arguments, you can use the expansion operator {*}:

```
callingfunction {*}{
  "argument1"
  "argument2 is longer"
  "argument3 is even more long"
  "argument4 is short again"
  "and then there are agrguments that are far longer than anything else seen before"
}
```

But the normal way to split a command across multiple lines is to escape the end of line using a backslash:

```
callingfunction \
  "argument1" \
  "argument2 is longer" \
  "argument3 is even more long" \
  "argument4 is short again" \
  "and then there are agrguments that are far longer than anything else seen before"
```

That will also allow variables and commands to be used as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I use the first example like `audit {*}{` the script crashes and says: **extra characters after close-brace.** If i use it wihtout the asterisk part like this: `audit {` it works. but it handles all arguments as one single block. i still need to be able to access every single argument within. The bottom example does not work and crashes the script. The editor (Visual Studio Code) flags everything as it does not recogznize this way of writing, either...

Comment: I tested both examples before posting. If they don't work for you, you must be doing something differently than what I posted.

Comment: i am using TCL 8.3 and have no way of upgrading. So maybe this is the source of the difference. I tested it in a huge environment where multiple scripts call other scripts. i will test this again in a single file just to rule out some cause of errors. will report back, thank you for your input.

Comment: When you're using a version of the software that is over 20 years old, it would be prudent to mention that in your question. Indeed, my first suggestion requires Tcl 8.5. But escaping newlines has been around for a long time. That should also work in 8.3. I just don't have such an ancient version installed that I can easily test it.

Comment: As i said i am stuck as this is the version that cisco has installed within their IOS-XE operating system. i would love to upgrade, trust me. Sadly, Cisco is just a granddad in that regard. I managed to get your second solution to work. It is very finniky with the amount of spaces after before and after the slash. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are stuck on Tcl 8.3 (which is very *very* **very** outdated!) you have to do this:

```
proc multilineEval args {
    set cmd {}
    foreach arg $args {
        foreach line [split $arg \n] {
            foreach word [uplevel 1 [list subst $line]] {
                lappend cmd $word
            }
        }
    }
    uplevel 1 $cmd
}

multilineEval callingfunction {
    "argument1"
    "argument2 is longer"
    "argument3 is even more long"
    "argument4 is short again"
    "and then there are agrguments that are far longer than anything else seen before"
}
```

Ugly! Handles tricky edge cases though.

---

Or you could put your longer arguments in variables with shorter names and find ways to not pass quite so many arguments.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work. it does not like the callingfunction after calling the function. but i managed to get the split accross multiple lines with the backslash solution to work as provided by Bron. Thanks for your input nevertheless.